# Error using React Markdown editor

Tags: javascript, reactjs, markdown

Hello I am trying to implement react markdown editor and I have used Jed Watson's http://jedwatson.github.io/react-md-editor/

But the problem is that, I am getting the error attached. Any thoughts what I am missing :(.. Has anyone encountered similar issue ?[image]

> ```
> import Editor from 'react-md-editor';
>
> state = {
>               code: '# React Markdown '            
>
> }
>
> updateCode = (newCode) => {
>       this.setState({
>           code: newCode
>       });
>     }
>
> Render:
>
> <Editor value={this.state.code} onChange={this.updateCode} />
> ```

Comment: The editor doesn't appear to be compatible with the version of React being used. It's expecting `PropTypes` to be part of React, but they were moved into their own package – [`prop-types`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/prop-types).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because of [PropTypes are deprecated since React 15.5.0](https://reactjs.org/blog/2017/04/07/react-v15.5.0.html#react), and the editor PropTypes usage is incompatible with the editor's React version.

After 15.5.0, they are moved to their own package, and we should use them as follows:

```
// After (15.5)
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
```

The repo / package you're using looks abandoned, but there's already submitted PR, that you can use: https://github.com/JedWatson/react-md-editor/pull/17

However, it's on your own to choose - should you fork the repo or use another React Markdown project.

Here are some alternatives:

- https://github.com/andrerpena/react-mde
- https://github.com/OpusCapita/react-markdown

Comment: @johnsam you're welcome! Please accept the answer, if it helped you. :)